# User cancelled WiX Bundle exe not uninstalled

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

When a user cancels our WiX bundle it appears to rollback.  The log shows all of the packages as rolled back.  But, not the bundle.  After cancel, the bundle is still listed in Programs and Features.  Double-clicking, or running bundle.exe again runs an Uninstall. Once the uninstall completes then the install can be run again.

Is this right?
One would expect the bundle to be uninstalled as a result of cancel.

Can we automatically uninstall a cancelled WiX bundle?